# Removing text in an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

So I've got this image and I'd like to be able to remove the text so that it's just a picture of the banner.

I don't know of any 'advanced techniques' so to speak, so what I have tried so far is eyedropping each section around each letter, and brushing over the text.

This is a messy (and long) process so I'm looking for a more efficient (and hopefully cleaner) way of doing this.

**The image in question:**

[image: Orange Banner]

Thanks!

Comment: this is a small image, no process is going to be perfect (at the same time, it won't need to be, exactly because of the image size)

Comment: A suggestion may be to redo it properly, and save it "clear witouth text", and later you can add text, because for instance, the borders of the banner are not great.

Comment: @Larme Sorry I forgot to mention that this image was cropped out of a screenshot, so I don't have the original files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to tackle this is using the lasso tool to trace the text and do a 'content aware' fill (edit - fill - content aware). Then brush over ugly edges with the same color and you're mostly good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have Adobe Illustrator and can work with vectors. Go to www.freepik.com website and find similar banner graphic. You will find plenty of graphics that look like that  (maybe different color). In Illustrator you can open the file edit text and save it as whatever you need.
Hope that helps. You could also you Photoshop to either paint over the text or cut out everything inside and replace all the color area with different gradient, but it's just more work and the quality of your banner is already very low.